# How to have advice not execute the function when conditions are met?

Tags: emacs, elisp, advising-functions, defadvice

How do you prevent the advised function from running when the advice returns nil?

```
(defadvice beginning-of-line (before test activate)
 nil)
```

-> Not running `beginning-of-line` at all.

EDIT: Just to take away your worries, I do not intend to use it on `beginning-of-line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `around` advice, as is:

```
(defadvice foo (around test activate)
  (if my-test
      ad-do-it))
```

The construct `ad-do-it` corresponds to running the original function.

Comment: This does not work for a `cond`. Actually, the around seems to cause the trouble. In this case it runs the advise, finds out it should run the function, but then it does the advise again!

Comment: This doesn't sound right! Are you sure your old advice isn't still active as well?

Comment: I am absolutely certain: closed and reopened emacs.

Comment: To elaborate, the function deletes several lines, and the advice has a cond which has (looking-at "(") in there. The last one of the `cond` is ad-do-it. Here's the thing: first of all it deletes several lines (because it is not looking at "("), but then after deleting those lines it is (looking-at "(") and then it also deletes  that "("

Comment: You should be able to run the function from here (all included): http://pastebin.com/AUenTCfG

Comment: I just tested it. It seems to work as intended -- whenever the point is at a parenthesis it, and its mate, are deleted. Otherwise things like the region is deleted. Try adding "message":s to convince yourself that things are not executed more than you expect.

Comment: The thing is, when you have some lines above a (defun) in empty space, it deletes the return characters as intended, but it also deletes the parentheses. It should only delete the enters.

Comment: Again, it works as intended here, using the code you posted... The `(defun)` is left intact and the empty lines are deleted.

Comment: Yea, when renaming the functions, this code does work! Thanks, I'll have to look again in my code to see what is going on.